# How can I make Internet Explorer use Window Post Message to run scripts across domains

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

A client is asking me to build a page that can be iframed into a parent page on a different domain, and for it to resize automatically.

After some trial and error, this is working properly in Chrome, Firefox, etc... But in IE11 I am getting a "SCRIPT5: Access is denied" error.

My resizing code on the parent page

```
    //Timer is used to prevent duplicate resize events
    var rtime;
    var timeout = false;
    var delta = 300;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        rtime = new Date();
        if (timeout === false) {
            timeout = true;
            //This shrinks the iframe before it provides a height value to prevent it growing exponentially
            iFrame.style.height = "1100px";
            setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        rtime = new Date();
        if (timeout === false) {
            timeout = true;
            setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
        }
    });
    
    function resizeend() {
        if (new Date() - rtime < delta) {
            setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
        } else {
            
            timeout = false;
            console.log('starting...');
            iframe = document.getElementById('iFrame'); 
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('sizing?', '*'); 
            // we have to listen for 'message' window.addEventListener('message', respondToSizingMessage, false); 
        }               
    }
}

handleSizingResponse = function(e) {

    console.log('begin response handling');
    console.log('origin '+ e.origin);

        var action = e.data.split(':')[0] 
      if(action == 'sizing') {
  
          
            var values = e.data.split(':')[1];
            var newHeight = values.split(',') [0] + 'px';
            //var newWidth = values.split(',') [1] + 'px';

          console.log ('New Height: ' + newHeight);
          iFrame = document.getElementById('iFrame');
          
          iFrame.style.height = newHeight;
          //iFrame.style.width = newWidth;
          } 
      else { 
            console.log("Unknown message: "+e.data); 
            } 
          
    } 
      
    window.addEventListener('message', handleSizingResponse, false);
```

My relevant code on the child page:

```
//Handle resize events
respondToSizingMessage = function(e) {  // e.data is the string sent by the origin with postMessage.
    console.log('resize event received by frame');
    if(e.data == 'sizing?') {
        
        var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

        //Get Body height
        var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

        //Send Body height
        e.source.postMessage('sizing:'+height+','+document.body.scrollWidth, e.origin); 
    };
}; 

//Listen for incoming messages, and call response function
window.addEventListener('message', respondToSizingMessage, false);
```

I'm unclear on how to work around this, if I should build a condition into my JS that performs differently when the browser is IE, or if I have to rewrite/approach this entirely differently.